# How do I select a field based on the value of another field in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which contains the following fields:

```
current_field
field_1
field_2
field_3
...etc...
```

current_field contains the name of the field to be selected.

If current_field contained "field_23", how would I construct the select statement to select current_field and field_23?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a giant `case` expression:

```
select (case when current_field = 'field_1' then field_1
             when current_field = 'field_2' then field_2
             . . . 
        end) as current_field_value
```

Note:  This requires that all the field values have the same (or compatible) types.

In general, this type of operation suggests that you have an issue with your data model.  This is not a typical type of expression.

A better data model would be to store this in two tables, something like:

- `entities` table with `entity_id`, `current_field`
- `fields` table with `entity_id`, `field_name`, `field_value`

Then you could express the logic as:

```
select e.*, f.*
from entities e join
     fields f
     on e.entity_id = f.entity_id
where f.field_name = e.current_field;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `CASE` expression

```
SELECT current_field
    ,CASE current_field 
       WHEN 'field_1' THEN field_1
       WHEN 'field_2' THEN field_2
       WHEN 'field_3' THEN field_3
     END as current_value
FROM tab
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL provides and option of prepared statement and execute it.

If your field **current_field** contains dynamic columns or if it contains the comma separated value, then you can try something like,

```
CREATE TABLE fieldDemo (
    current_field VARCHAR(256), 
    field_1 VARCHAR(16), 
    field_2 VARCHAR(16), 
    field_3 VARCHAR(256)
);

INSERT INTO fieldDemo VALUES('field_2,field_3','f1','f2','f3');

SELECT current_field FROM fieldDemo INTO @t;

SET @tm = CONCAT('select ',@t, '  from fieldDemo');

PREPARE stmt FROM @tm

EXECUTE stmt;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[MySQL document Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)